# Tabbar Item connected to ibaction

Tags: ios, uitabbaritem

I am trying to find a way to make an item of the TabBar acting as a "UIbutton".
I would like when pressing to this item just make it work as a ibaction method.

I tried several implementation as :

```
   -(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
   }
```

But I was not able to get the method working.

What will be the best solution to fake an item function of a tabbar, and make it open an UIActionSheet for example ?

Comment: Did you assign the tab bars delegate?

Comment: I doubt if you'd be sticking with the HCI guidelines by doing what you are proposing to do, but hey, it's your design!

Answer (score 1):

Try using an IBOutlet and UITabBarDelegate in your viewController.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate> {
  IBOutlet UITabBar* tabBar;
}
@end
```

Connect the UITabBar to that IBOutlet in Interface Builder.

Set the delegate to 'self' in your viewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  tabBar.delegate = self;
}
```

And set up the delegate method with some way to differentiate the tabs:

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
  NSLog(item.title);
  if([item.title isEqualToString:@"some label"]) {
     // do something for this specific button
  }
}
```

(This is an old post, but I had the same question. Hopefully this saves someone else the same trouble.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the tabBarController **shouldSelectViewController** delegate method.  Override this.  Return NO on the tab you want to display an ActionSheet from, and instead instantiate the ActionSheet in this method.

You'll be required to have a placeholder UIViewController in place of this tab.

As mentioned above, this goes against Apple HIG and might be reason for your app to be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out! These people create a tabBar with a uibutton in it! http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

Full source code:
https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

I tried the code some time ago and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Call your action method in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view of the tab bar item selected.